# Best way to set HTML head title in a Spring+Tiles2 application?

Tags: spring, layout, usability, tiles2

I have a usability problem in my Spring webapp which uses Tiles as the view technology.
At the moment all of the pages display the same `HEAD_TITLE` and the `PAGE_TITLE` is page specific:

```
 <html>
 <head><title>HEAD_TITLE</title></head>
 <body>
 <h1>PAGE_TITLE</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is a major usability problem as the browsers history lists all different pages of the application with the same title. The reason why the `HEAD_TITLE` is same for all pages is that I haven't found a reasonable way to use the `PAGE_TITLE` as the `HEAD_TITLE`.

In most cases the `PAGE_TITLE` comes from a message bundle with `<fmt:message />` tag and 
some parameters are passed to it. The Tiles layout is such that the `HEAD_TITLE` should be already set at that point because all pages of the webapp use the same common layout which defines the `<HEAD>` elements of the pages amongst other stuff.

Any suggestions how to fix this usability problem? Should I set a "pageTitle" request attribute in my Spring controllers for all pages and use that as the `PAGE_TITLE` and also as the `HEAD_TITLE`? Or is it possible to somehow set the HEAD_TITLE in the page specific JSP?

Answer (score 1):

Create a general definition and define headTitle and pageTitle attributes.

```
<definition name="threeColumnLayout" template="/WEB-INF/ThreeColumnLayout.jsp" >
    <put-attribute name="headTitle" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="pageTitle" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="left" value="/WEB-INF/left.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="middle" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="right" value="/WEB-INF/right.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Set appropriate values in more specific definition.

```
<definition name="/user/new" extends="threeColumnLayout">
    <put-attribute name="headTitle" value="Administration" />
    <put-attribute name="pageTitle" value="Create User" />
    <put-attribute name="middle" value="WEB-INF/views/UserCreate.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Use `<tiles:getAsString />` tag to retrieve such values in jsp page.

```
<head>
    <title><tiles:getAsString name="headTitle"/></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <title><tiles:getAsString name="pageTitle"/></title>
    </h1>
</body>
```

Reference:- http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tagreference.html#tiles:getAsString